# Newer programmer - trying to port an off canvas menu to a web component

Tags: javascript

hoping for some help. I am trying to port an off canvas menu into a Web Component. I used the off canvas menu from w3schools as my model for this.

I was able to move the html and styles into the components template and render, I am trying to add the logic into the class and dont know where to start with this. It is moving two of the styles 250 px to do that toggle effect. Any guidance is appreciated. I am teaching myself this, so guidance to best practice is appreciated as well, JS and Web Components arent my wheelhouse. I have been reading MDN and trying to learn the proper way to do this, thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Web Component</title>
</head>
<body>

    <offcanvas-menu></offcanvas-menu>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//template variables
const template = document.createElement('template');
//styling and html for template
template.innerHTML = `
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <button>Open</button>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right.</p>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>`;

class OffCanvasMenu extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    
  }

  connectedCallback() {
      //open the DOM
      this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
      //append my template
      this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
      const button = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("button");
      button.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick);

    }

    //console's out so button works
    handleClick(e) {
      console.log("my button")
    }  
  }

window.customElements.define('offcanvas-menu', OffCanvasMenu);

//how do I integrate this logic
/*
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}*/
```

Comment: You can use the Lit framework or the Ficus framework - they provide reactivity similar to Vue so you can declaratively define your HTML template as JavaScript template literal.

Comment: Thanks. My goal is to do this with vanilla js and no use of a framework.

Comment: I do not see any problem with the vanilla JS - use it as it fits.